# How to make a call-able function from my python Class, without having to run the entire file if called?

Tags: python, pandas, function, class

I just managed to create a **coreCalc()** Class in Python. All works fine. 
Now I want to actually call that algorithm from coreCalc() from another python file, without having to run the entire original Class file, I believe because currently my Class is dependent on the entire code above.

Can someone give me some pointers on how to solve this question?

```
**My code**:

   #references
   import gspread
   from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
   import pandas as pd
   import csv
   import time
   import requests

   #using creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('/Users/Miauw/Miauw/github/Miauw/Token/token.json', scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)

    # Find a workbook by name and open the first sheet
    sheet = client.open("IFTTT_Webhooks_Events").sheet1

    #get data directly from google sheet.
    data = sheet.get_all_values()
    headers = data.pop(0)
    # capture data into dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)

    df_array = [ (df["Statement 3"].iloc[-1]),
        (df["Statement 2"].iloc[-1]),
        (df["Statement 3"].iloc[-1]),
        (df["Statement 3"].iloc[-1])
    ]

    #function for calculating user lonelienss based on UCLA Lonliness scoring (theory) 
    class coreCalc:
        def __init__(self):
        #assign loneliness-scores to the various user-responses
            for i in range(len(df_array)):
                if df_array[i] == 'Often':
                    df_array[i] = 3
                elif df_array[i] == 'Sometimes':
                    df_array[i] = 2
                elif df_array[i] == 'Rarely':
                    df_array[i] = 1
                elif df_array[i] == 'Never':
                    df_array[i] = 0
                #obtain sum of values for final scoring
            print(sum(map(int,df_array)))

    #coreCalc()
```

Comment: Make it easy for us to help you... remove the numbering. If someone wants to post a solution, should they be expected to fiddle with those line numbers?

Comment: @tdelaney apologies, didn't think about it when I copied my code from VIM.

Comment: Why is `coreCalc` a class at all, instead of a regular function? Also, the algorithm is useless without the `df_array` whose initialization you are trying to skip.

Comment: @chepner, I am not a coder much sir, I am learning Python as I go now. I just read about local and global variables etc. Perhaps I should do something with that? Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: `coreCalc` directly uses things that require the entire module to be evaluated first. It's not clear from your question what you think you can skip.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to ensure that this code can be called from another module is to import the module. Unfortunately, you have some initialization code at the top of the module. I would recommend throwing all of this inside of some base class and then extending it from coreCalc. Below I have thrown an example of what this would look like.

```py
#references
import csv
import time

import gspread
import requests
import pandas as pd
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


class CalcBase:
    def __init__(self):
        #using creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
        self.scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
        self.creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('/Users/Miauw/Miauw/github/Miauw/Token/token.json', scope)
        self.client = gspread.authorize(creds)

        # Find a workbook by name and open the first sheet
        self.sheet = client.open("IFTTT_Webhooks_Events").sheet1

        #get data directly from google sheet.
        self.data = sheet.get_all_values()
        self.headers = data.pop(0)
        # capture data into dataframe
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)

        self.df_array = [ (df["Statement 3"].iloc[-1]),
            (df["Statement 2"].iloc[-1]),
            (df["Statement 3"].iloc[-1]),
            (df["Statement 3"].iloc[-1])
        ]

#function for calculating user lonelienss based on UCLA Lonliness scoring (theory) 
class coreCalc(CalcBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)

    #assign loneliness-scores to the various user-responses
        for i in range(len(self.df_array)):
            if self.df_array[i] == 'Often':
                self.df_array[i] = 3
            elif self.df_array[i] == 'Sometimes':
                self.df_array[i] = 2
            elif self.df_array[i] == 'Rarely':
                self.df_array[i] = 1
            elif self.df_array[i] == 'Never':
                self.df_array[i] = 0
            #obtain sum of values for final scoring
        print(sum(map(int,self.df_array)))

#coreCalc()
```

Comment: All you are doing is shifting the initialization code from import time to instantiation time. Worse, you are *duplicating* the initialization every time you create an instance of `coreCalc, where before it was done only *once* when the module was imported.